# how to call String in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to showmodal method, but getting error while taken string. if pass int it calls, how to take string in javascript.

```
<script>
    var table = ' <table id="example" class="table table-striped " width="100%"> <thead>';
    table += ' <tr class="success">';
    table += '<th>Sender</th>';
    table += '<th>Recipient</th>';
    table += '<th>Mail Server</th>';
    table += '<th>Arrival Time</th>';
    table += '</tr>';
    table += '</thead>';
    table += '<tbody>';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.u.length; i++) {
        table += '<tr><td><a href="javascript:showModal('+data.u[i].sender+')">';
        table += data.u[i].sender + '</a></td><td>' + data.u[i].receiver;
        table += '</td><td>' + data.u[i].mail_server + '</td></tr>';
    }
    table += '</tbody>';
    table += '</table>';

    $("#resp1").html(table);

    function showModal (id) {   
        alert("hi ");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is `data` defined?

Comment: What error you are getting? Have you console log?

Comment: where is your `data` array or object??? if possible then write it in this question ??

Comment: You code works just fine, when i run your code, (replacing data) i get the alert.

Comment: getting json values in data through calling ajax, table values are displaying but inside table I am not getting how to call java script.

Comment: I think you are missing the quotation Marks, try this ...href="javascript:showModal(\''+data.u[i].sender+'\')">...

Comment: I have to pass sender name to javascript function, sender value getting by data.u[i].sender in table.

Comment: thanks to all. it is working when use <a href="javascript:showModal(\' '+data.u[i].sender+'\')">

Comment: i formatted your code now. please do this yourself in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing quotation marks in the function call

Change this line

```
table += '<tr><td><a href="javascript:showModal('+data.u[i].sender+')">';
```

To this line

```
table += '<tr><td><a href="javascript:showModal(\''+data.u[i].sender+'\')">';
```